# How can I contact the author of deleted question if I have an answer to their question?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I am referring to this question: [Sort algorithm to create a polygon from points with only right angle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74554553/sort-algorithm-to-create-a-polygon-from-points-with-only-right-angle).

I believe I have a solution to this question.  Is it possible to contact the author to find out if they are still interested?

Comment: Alternatively, you can ask a question by yourself and self-answer it if you're interested in sharing the answer to everyone else (not only the asker).

Comment: Given that the question appears to have no downvotes, and was self-deleted within a few days of being posted, it's likely that they have found a solution themselves, or no longer need to solve the problem.

Comment: You don't, if I'm honest. Commenting on a different post by the user, in my opinion, isn't correct as that's not what comments are meant to be for; they are for getting clarification on the post that the comment is on *not* asking the OP about a different post. If you have the priviledge you can vote to undelete the post and then follow it so you get a notification if 2 other users agree with the undeletion, but this doesn't happen often as there's no undelete review queue, it's just part of the [moderation tools](//stackoverflow.com/tools).

Comment: Unfortunately I do not recall the id of the OP, so cannot approach them via another posting.  If reposting the question myself is okay I might do that. It is a bit frustrating. I had done 90% of the work and was about to post the solution, only to find it had gone . . .

Comment: push comes to shove, Stack Overflow is not a platform for helping individuals. Don't try, you may end up breaking rules by trying to be a good person.

Comment: “If reposting the question myself is okay I might do that.” - Which is the reason the author’s actions is one of the most toxic actions that exists today at Stack Overflow (speaking of the situation where a user asks a question then deletes their question).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't contact them, and please do not try to reach out to them by commenting on some unrelated post.

The truth is that whether they are interested or not is not relevant on Stack Overflow. If you know an answer that you think might be useful to someone else then you should ask a question yourself and post your own answer to it.

Comment: (But do please first check for an existing, non-deleted question that's close enough.)

Comment: I have reposted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74666413/sort-algorithm-to-create-a-polygon-from-points-with-only-right-angles)